# Configure GSM connection using shell (nmcli)

Tags: command-line, network-manager, configuration, usb-modem

I have a system without X display and I want to use nmcli to configure my usb cell modem. I can get the modem working using Ubuntu Desktops GSM-Wizard (X/GUI). But what is the console alternative on Ubuntu Server?

```
$ nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8

$ nmcli dev status
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
ttyUSB2    gsm               disconnected 
wlan0      802-11-wireless   connected  

$ nmcli dev wifi con "SSID1"
# works for new WIFI connections only, how to set up GSM?
```

Answer (score 4):

Without having tried it myself, but the instructions on http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Networking/CLI seem useful.

The link mentions that
`nmcli connection edit con-name <name of new connection>` asks you relevant questions in order to set your connection up.

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/114006/71928) is a bit contradictory in that it mentions smth like `nmcli dev gsm con "Mobile"` to create a connection.

[This link](http://mehulved.com/2012/02/connecting-gsm-modem-via-cli-using-networkmanager/) mentions adding the following lines to `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` and using `nmcli con up id <connection id>` to activate the connection:

```
[connection]
id=MTNL
uuid=15d742f1-2b5a-421e-9f27-fcb1fc26d72c
type=gsm
autoconnect=true

[ipv4]
method=auto

[gsm]
number=*99#
username=mtnl
password=mtnl123
apn=gprsppsmum

[serial]
baud=115200
```

Comment: Note: newer NetworkManager responds to "nmcli connection edit con-name..." with "Error: 'con' command 'edit' is not valid."; also for "nmcli dev gsm con "Mobile"", I get "Error: 'dev' command 'gsm' is not valid.", see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114364/nmcli-no-longer-allow-settings-modification